# How to remove horizontal lines inside primefaces p:panelGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have lines horizontally inside the panel as you can see in screen shot.
Ideally I would like to have only the border which should show as a box and would like to remove the horizontal lines.

I have tried with

```
.ui-panelgrid tr
{   
 border-width: 0px !important;    
}
```

however this removes border completely.

How can I set the border as a box for the panel and no lines inside the panel?

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Just check for that style in browser developer tools and override in you local. And can you update with code snippet related to this screenshot